# does the equivalence of Poisson and conditional logit models hold for fixed effect panel data and negative binomial models?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

Guimaraes et al. (Rev Econ Stat, 2003, 85/1) describe the conditions under which the results from poisson regression models and conditional logit models are equivalent. I am trying to find out whether this result also holds i) for fixed effects panel data; ii) for negative binomial models; and iii) (for completeness' sake) fixed effect negative binomial models. It would be extremely helpful if you could point me to some relevant literature, if it exists.

Comment: Can you give a full citation? Off-the-cuff I doubt iii holds, as the estimate of the dispersion parameter makes the negative binomial panel model not really "fixed effects" - see *Fixed–Effects Negative Binomial Regression Models* ([Allison & Waterman, 2002](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/1467-9531.00117)), PDF [here](http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/Allison.Waterman.pdf), for discussion.

Comment: @AndyW The full citation is: Guimaraes, P., O. Figueirdo, and D. Woodward, 'A tractable approach to the firm location decision problem', the Review of Economics and Statistics, 2003, 85(1): 201-204. doi:10.1162/003465303762687811

Comment: @AndyW And if I understand Allison&Waterman correctly, I could estimate unconditional fixed effects models by including dummy variables in the specification of the mean. The incidental parameter problem might exist, but seems to be small in this case.

Comment: Well that is the recommendation by Allison in that particular paper, supported by a simulation study with a fairly large cross section (100) and a small number of repeated observations (2). It is unclear to me if the same advice would hold in different circumstances, and/or with more interesting unobserved fixed effects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

- Guimaraes, P., and Lindrooth, R.C. (2007), [Controlling for Overdispersion in Grouped Conditional Logit Models: A Computationally Simple Application of Dirichlet-Multinomial Regression](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1368-423X.2007.00215.x/abstract), *The Econometrics Journal*. 10: 439–452. doi: 10.1111/j.1368-423X.2007.00215.x

I think it shows the connection to the negative binomial.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user61841. Would you mind expanding on the connection shown there a little? The citation is helpful, but a little more information would be nice. At present, this is more of a comment than an answer.